# Ubuntu 18.04 Cannot "Select All" in Folder

Tags: nautilus, filemanager

Ubuntu used to have a Right Click option to "Select All" inside a Folder to perform an action with all the Files within a particular folder. Now with this new installation of 18.04 I don't see that Option in the folders when I right click. I looked around all over the place in Preferences and I do not see anywhere I can change the Options or Preferences to make this happen. Seems really awkward not having that in the File folder list. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Can't you work around it by marking the first item in the folder, scroll to the bottom, press shift and mark the last item ... just until someone find the missing "Select all" ?

Comment: @SorenA That is a tedious workaround I would not find acceptable. Error prone 5 seconds involving scrolling and visual scanning instead of 0.5 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

You will in principle find the option "Select All" when you right-click an empty space in the folder. The issue with nautilus is, however, that you cannot access that menu using right-click if your view is filled with file and folder names. This is a bug as old as the street. On Ubuntu launchpad, there is a report of [2010](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus-open-terminal/+bug/597678) and one of [2013](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1179744), never marked as duplicates and never actionned.

[Reported in 2012 on Gnome issues](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689768), the issue is finally solved in Nautilus 3.30, where the redesign of the path bar allows to have this menu available anytime as a right right-click on the folder in the path bar. Ubuntu 18.04, however, still ships with nautilus 3.26, because that was the last version that supports icons on the desktop.

There are quick alternatives to select all items, however:

- Use the shortcut key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> to quickly select all items.
- Display the right-click menu for the folder by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, where you find "Select all" among the options.

Comment: Time is flying, and we almost have flying cars, but the bug (is it a feature?) is still there. It is year 2022, and I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 with the same problem.

Comment: @PaulJurczak You don't as indicated in the answer. There is the ⁞ button to the right of the path bar that makes that menu available,

Comment: Not on my system. Clicking that button opens a large format drop down menu with a few blank choices.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solutions given with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>, I just found the *Select all* right-click feature when your pictures are displayed in a certain way.

There is a button up right (the name of which I do not know) showing four little squares - if this is shown, there is no *Select all*.

However, if you go to that button and click it once, there will be only two squares and two lines - it is a different presentation mode now for your pictures and files.
In this mode, the right-click option for *Select all* works nicely.